# How to use web-safe colors in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, colors

I have searched google, but I cannot find anything out there on applying a pure web-safe color in xcode. I have found one that is exactly what I need, but for some reason, xcode keeps rejecting it with the error "expected expression". I have no idea what expression I am missing. Shouldn't adding a color be as simple as this:

```
[self.label setBackgroundColor:#FF0033];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this was what I needed:

```
    [self.label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:66/255.0
                                     green:33/255.0
                                      blue:33/255.0
                                     alpha:1.0]];
```

Answer (score 4):

I should be that simple, but setBackgroundColor needs a UIColor object and not an RGB like you are providing...

You can use this to fix it:

```
#define HEXCOLOR(c) [UIColor colorWithRed:((c>>24)&0xFF)/255.0 
 green:((c>>16)&0xFF)/255.0 
 blue:((c>>8)&0xFF)/255.0 
 alpha:((c)&0xFF)/255.0];

// usage:
UIColor* c = HEXCOLOR(0xFF0033FF);
```

If you don't need the Alpha you can just set it to 1 and adjust the bit shifts.